# Nouveau kernel rejected pushbuf on Allegro5-C++

Tags: c++, kernel, nvidia, allegro

I'm in trouble with this:
I've installed Allegro5 on Ubuntu, and compiled my Helloworld project

```css
#include <allegro5\allegro.h> #include <allegro5\allegro_native_dialog.h> int main(void) {
  ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display=NULL;
  if(!al_init()) {
    al_show_native_message_box(NULL, NULL, NULL, "failed to initialize allegro!", NULL, NULL);
    return -1;
  }
  display=al_create_display(640,
  480);
  if(!display) {
    al_show_native_message_box(NULL, NULL, NULL, "failed to initialize display!", NULL, NULL);
    return -1;
  }
  al_destroy_display(display);
  return 0;
}
```

with " g++ -Wall TestProgram.cc `pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0 allegro_font-5.0 allegro_ttf-5.0` ".
Running it on terminal, it gives me this error (or crash?) message:

```css
nac@NAC:~$ ./a.out 
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: Bad file descriptor
nouveau: ch0: krec 0 pushes 1 bufs 1 relocs 0
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000000 00000002 00000004 00000004 00000000
nouveau: ch0: psh 00000000 00000004a8 00000004bc
nouveau:    0x00107b00
nouveau:    0x00000000
nouveau:    0x20217000
nouveau:    0x00000003
nouveau:    0x1000f010
```

After some tests I saw that it crashes on or after "al_destroy_display(display);", in fact, after that error I must ctrl+C to end the program.

How can I do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a few months old, but it comes up as the first hit when searching for this error. I had the same error running LinuxMint 17.2 with Allegro 5.0.10, and solved it by updating my graphics card (GeForce GTX 460) driver. Hope this helps future users.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Rstudio (it is quite famous bug on rstudio)

It is proposed to run it using the following command in terminal:

```
QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1 rstudio
```

so, in your case i think:

```
QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1 ./a.out
```